# Is there a way to find the titlebar height and window borders in GNOME3?

Tags: bash, gnome-3

xwininfo used to return the dimensions of the window including the border and titlebar until GNOME2. Now the same command returns the dimensions of the actual window without the borders and titlebar. So is there another command that I can use in a shell script to add the two together to get the real dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like

```
xwininfo -frame
```

provides the full height of the window, including the title bar. Although I am not sure about the width shown, which seems a bit overstated.

Comment: I tried that but the dimensions returned by that also includes the window's shadows so it's bigger than the actual dimensions. Unless there is a way to figure how many pixels of it are just the shadows, there doesn't seem to be a way to get the real dimensions. For now I've just hard coded the shadow size as 9 pixels in my case.